# Magento 2: How to I solve product image not changing in admin panel

Tags: magento2, admin, configurable-product, product-images

I have a Configurable product.

I change the image of config product

**before saving ::**

[image]

**after saving  ::**
[image]

Product Image not changing I tried 3 time

How I can solve this?

`pub/media/catalog/product`

[image]

Comment: What's permission for your media folder ?

Comment: where the media folder is ...

Comment: Check the permission of magento_root/pub/media

Comment: folder pub/media 755

Comment: Can yo confirm that image uploaded at media folder after save ? Check at pub/media/catalog/product/ ?

Comment: showing many folders

Comment: i added screen shot of  catelog/product/       floder

Answer (score 0):

1) have to **set  image role** :

**- Base

 - Small

 - Thumbnail**

the product image under look like this

[image]

after u can save this it will work